# Vague convergence VS Weak convergence of probability measure.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Something looks strange to me (I put a screen shot of my lecture, because I want to be sure to not miss any information). So I have the following text :

[image]

And then I have an an exemple that if $X_n$ is uniformly on $[-n,n]$, then the sequence of measure $(\mu_n)$ defined by $$\mu_n(A)=\mathbb P\{X_n\in A\},\quad A\in \mathscr B(\mathbb R),$$
(i.e. $A$ a Borel set) converges vaguely but not weakly.

**Question** If you see Remark 3.25, it is say that weak convergence and vague convergence for probability measure is equivalent, but $(\mu_n)$ is a probability sequence that is vaguely convergent, but not weakly convergent. Did I misunderstood something or is my lecture has contradiction and is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

$(\mu_n)$ converges vaguely to the measure $0$, which is obviously not a probability measure. So, there is no contradiction. What you have is :

> Let $(\mu_n)$ being a sequence of probability measure and $\mu$ being a probability measure. Then, $(\mu_n)$ converges weakly to $\mu$ if and only if $(\mu_n)$ converges vaguely to $\mu$.

As your counter-example shows, if $\mu$ is not a probability measure, the converse is not true. Nevertheless, the implication is always true.

Comment: So if $\mu_n\to \mu$  vaguely and if $\mu$ is not a probability measure, then $\mu_n\not\rightarrow \mu$ weakly ?

Comment: I don't think that your statement is correct, in the sense that even if $\mu$ is not a probability measure, then $\mu_n\Rightarrow \mu$ vaguely and weakly can holds (I don't have any example in mind, but I wouldn't be surprised that it works). Nevertheless, if $\mu$ is a probability measure, then if $\mu_n\Rightarrow \mu$ to one of the two topology, then it converges according to the other topology.

Comment: Just to conclude,  notice that if $\mu_n\Rightarrow \mu$ weakly, then the convergence also holds vaguely. (That always work). It's just that the converse doesn't holds whenever $\mu$ is not a probability measure.