Can we replace "bounded continuous functions" by "compactly supported continuous functions" in Portmanteau theorem (in non-compact spaces)?
Let $\{P_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ and $P$ be Borel probability measures on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$.
One of the equivalent statements in Portmanteau theorem is that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_X f(x)dP_n=\int_X f(x)dP, \forall C_b(X)$$

where $C_b(X)$ means the space of all bounded continuous functions on $X$.
Now I wonder if I can replace $C_b(X)$ by $C_c(X)$, the space of all compactly supported continuous functions on $X$ and still get an equivalent statement. This shouldn't be true (otherwise Portmanteau theorem should include this) but it is also hard for me to find a counterexample.
As a side question, besides $X$ being compact itself, are there other conditions that can make this equivalence hold for $C_b(X)$ vs. $C_c(X)$?

PS: The situation I often work with is when $X$ is a homogeneous space of Lie groups and $P$ is a Haar measure. It would be great if one can have a counterexample in this environment.

See K L Chung's book for a discussion of 'vague convergence'.

@geetha290krm I am not sure which theorem/proposition you were referring to but Chung's book doesn't seems to have terms like "compactly supported"by searching...

Look at vague convergence in the index.

@geetha290krm Yes I was looking at that section 4.3  vague convergence from his 3rd ed. of the book....but didn't get your point

Does this help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3891579/vague-convergence-vs-weak-convergence-of-probability-measure

@geetha290krm Thanks! Also perhaps here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313986/are-vague-convergence-and-weak-convergence-of-measures-both-weak-convergence
